# Brocolli Plugin ENOENT no such file error in Docker

Tags: javascript, docker, ember.js, broccolijs

I'm using `Ember-cli 2.11` and `brocoli-asset-rev 2.4.5` and `"ember-cli-emblem": "0.8.2-beta.2"`. I am also using `docker`

I just created a `component` and then I get this error.

```
  The Broccoli Plugin: [Funnel: Funnel (test index)] failed with:
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/monty.lennie/tmp/funnel-input_base_path-4h2cnQAn.tmp/index.html'
        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:982:18)
        at symlink (/monty.lennie/node_modules/symlink-or-copy/index.js:79:26)
        at Function.symlinkOrCopySync [as sync] (/monty.lennie/node_modules/symlink-or-copy/index.js:65:5)
        at Funnel._copy (/monty.lennie/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:492:19)
        at Funnel.processFile (/monty.lennie/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:475:8)
        at Funnel.applyPatch [as _applyPatch] (/monty.lennie/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:389:12)
        at Funnel.<anonymous> (/monty.lennie/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:343:10)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Funnel.processFilters (/monty.lennie/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:342:11)

    The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
        at Funnel.Plugin (/monty.lennie/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:7:31)
        at new Funnel (/monty.lennie/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:58:10)
        at EmberApp.testIndex (/monty.lennie/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:775:15)
        at EmberApp.toArray (/monty.lennie/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1681:43)
        at EmberApp.toTree (/monty.lennie/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1696:30)
        at module.exports (/monty.lennie/ember-cli-build.js:23:14)
        at CoreObject.setupBroccoliBuilder (/monty.lennie/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:84:19)
        at CoreObject.init (/monty.lennie/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:64:10)
        at CoreObject.superWrapper [as init] (/monty.lennie/node_modules/core-object/lib/assign-properties.js:32:18)
        at CoreObject.Class (/monty.lennie/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:32:33)
```

Answer (score 0):

the `tests` directory needed an `index.html` file.